# how to connect linux/centos machine to trunk port

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking, vlan

I'm trying to connect Centos7 Machine to trunk port, which is having multiple vlan tagged. How do i add multiple ips single ethernet or how to define vlan id for specific subnet.

Comment: What is you question? How to connect to the machine or how to truncate ports?

Comment: My question is how to connected linux machine to a trunk port or in simple word how to connect linux  machine to a switch port which is passing more than one Vlan from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, VLAN tagging is handled with subinterfaces according to the naming scheme `ifX.N`, where `ifX` is interface X and `N` is the VLAN ID.  So, if you are attached to this switch via interface `eth0`, traffic to/from VLAN 10 will appear on `eth0.10`, and traffic to/from VLAN25 will appear on `eth0.25`.

You will need to create the subinterfaces, with eg

```
ifconfig eth0.10 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

This can be automated in CentOS with a file such as

```
[me@bill ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.10
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth0.10
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.10.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2001:db8:6049:10::1/64
```

Comment: adding  "VLAN=yes" and VLAN_ID=<Vlan_ID> will help  ?

Comment: @root what I posted above works for me, as-is; that is, it's taken from a live CentOS box doing a lot of VLANning.  I can't say whether it'll work for you, but it's what I'd try first.

Comment: your configuration is working fine for me too. thanks for your help :)